# Can you run Windows Client VM's on Azure with an MSDN Operating Systems subscription?

Tags: windows, azure, msdn

I have spent hours attempting to answer a very basic question about Azure and MSDN.  Microsoft documentation and support is very poor (and their pricing very high), but because I must continue to develop applications for Windows as a contract developer and I wish to have a backup and test development machine, I have no choice but to submit to their requirements.

I would like to answer what I think is a simple question: If I purchase an "MSDN Operating Systems" subscription (as opposed to a "Visual Studio Professionl with MSDN" subscription), will this enable the "Windows Client" VM option on Azure?  Or, am I required to purchase the much more expensive "Visual Studio Professionl with MSDN" subscription in order to have the Windows Client VM option in Microsoft Azure?

Note that the "feature comparison" between these two MSDN choices [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/msdn-subscriptions-vs/#AdditionalPageSections_1) has no bullet point in the "Microsoft Azure" line-item for the "MSDN Operating Systems":

[image: What does the lack of a bullet in the Microsoft Azure line-item for the MSDN Operating Systems subscription mean?]

... However, this could just mean that you don't receive any monthly credit for Azure usage - not that the Windows Client VM is not available for this Azure-MSDN connection.  But then again, maybe my fear is correct - that the Windows Client VM option will not be available on Azure, even if I pay for the MSDN Operating Systems subscription.

As I've noted, after literally hours of trying to answer this question, I can't (the Microsoft references are useless).

**Can you run Windows Client VM's on Azure with an MSDN Operating Systems subscription?**

Comment: I assumed there would be serial closevoters buzzing around on this question.  Please note that Microsoft Azure *officially* points to StackOverflow as one of the two locations to obtain non-charged customer support regarding Azure sales questions (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/).  If you have issues with questions about Azure appearing on StackOverflow, please contact Microsoft.  I also note that this is a serious question.  I'm a programmer and I need to know how I can set up Windows Client in a cloud VM environment without paying $200 to Microsoft to ask the question.

Answer (score 3):

This post http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/29/windows-client-images-on-azure/ states that the following MSDN subcriptions qualify for Windows Client VMS for dev and test:

Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN

· Visual Studio Premium with MSDN

· MSDN Platforms

· Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN

· Visual Studio Professional with MSDN

So it looks like the answer is no.

Tim